# Q&A Chart to Report

Tags: powerbi

I made a question to the Q&A input in a dashboard in PowerBI and I want to send the resulting chart to a report page in the web client, I only see the option to send it to a dashboard, but not the report. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

That an interesting idea that's not supported today. You can submit an idea at http://ideas.PowerBI.com .